# How to create an empty JsonNode?

Tags: java, jackson, jsonnode

I am trying to set an empty node as a value of some other json node. `new JsonNode()` didn't work as that is protected.

Example:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = externalSource(); // <--This is the parent json node
((ObjectNode) jsonNode).set("fieldName", new JsonNode()); // <-- I want to replace the existing 
// value of fieldName with an empty one
```

This will not work currently.

Any particular way we can do this?

Comment: Hello, have you tried this so far? 
`ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();` 
Also what do you mean it didn't work?

Comment: The constructor is not public, it's protected. So a client can not use that directly to instantiate `JsonNode`. It can only be used by subclasses extending the `JsonNode` class.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, you have an already existing jsonnode and you want to add to it a new field like `"empty": {}`?

Comment: I think I found the solution. Can use object mapper's `getNodeFactory` and then `textNode(...)` etc to create JsonNodes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
```

or you can also do like you said in the comment above,

```
JsonNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
```

after that you can map the values,

```
JsonNode node = mapper.valueToTree(fromValue);
```